# QGIS QT .ui not displaying attribute table value

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qt-designer

Following tutorial 6.3.6, Creating a New Form (the first introduction of Qt designer).

Seems very basic. Create a point layer with two attributes: name (text 80) and age (text 80). Then in QT designer create a .ui with name (QLineEdit) and age (QSpinBox)

I go to use the .ui in QGIS.

The form renders (but free space around the QLineEdit seems too large and very clunky).
Name - is populated from values from the table. 
Age - is populated with 0, does not show the value from the table. (very odd)

Edits to name and age work fine, they are retained back in the table fine. Its just the initial display of age as 0 (not the age from the table) that's odd.

The autogenerated form works fine, both fields are populated with values from the table.

Seems odd that age defaults to 0 in QT? Perhaps this is by design with a spinbox default?

Brand new to QT designer (coming from a MSFT VBA environment for forms). I note there are 1500 pages of documentation on QT designer (O.K. that's pretty intimidating.) Wondering with ample experience in creating UI in MSFT how long does it take to become productive on the QT side? Are there any quick tips, posts, "got yas", tutorials, etc. to get productive on QT designer quickly?